# Porting "WINAPI" datatype from Windows to Linux

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm converting Windows Networking Source Code in C to Linux. in this progress, I see this line, and don't know how to convert it :

```
DWORD WINAPI functionA(LPVOID lpParam) {

}
```

I meet error when compile : expected initializer before "functionA"

I have add some line of code :

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
```

about WINAPI. I don't pretty sure how to change this. I have change in two case:

```
#define WINAPI CDECL
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

but still meet above problem. How can I fix this ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WINAPI is not a datatype but a calling convention. For Linux you can drop WINAPI alltogether or just put this in the appropriate header file:

```
#define WINAPI
```

Comment: @alk; someone who is converting Windows Networking Source Code to Linux should understand.

Comment: Someone doing so, shouldn't even have the need to ask this question.